# Strange ORA-942 when using DBMS_CRYPTO but table exists

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, user-roles

This is very strange, and not easy to explain, so please bear with me.

Oracle 12.2.0.1 on Linux x86_64.

We have a user called `BATCH` who has minimal privileges.

```
CREATE USER batch IDENTIFIED BY batch
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users;

GRANT CREATE SESSION TO batch;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CRYPTO TO batch;
```

The is a PLSQL package in a schema called `ATLED` which is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ALTED.the_pkh AUTHID current_user AS
   PROCEDURE crttab;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ALTED.the_pkh AS
   PROCEDURE crttab IS
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE atled.the_tab AS SELECT id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(cc,2) AS cc FROM ARCHIVE.table_b';
   END crttab;
END;
/
```

We are using **Code Based Access Control** (CBAC - 12c feature) to restrict/control/allow certain canned actions to an otherwise toothless user, so we create a wrapper procedure, grant that a high priv role, and grant execute on that to the batch user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALTED.wrapper_crttab AS
   PROCEDURE p1 IS
      CURSOR c1 is SELECT * FROM SESSION_PRIVS;
   BEGIN
      FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r1.privilege );
      END LOOP;
   END;
BEGIN
   p1;
   ALTED.the_pkh.crttab;
END;
/

GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE TO ALTED;
GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE ALTED.wrapper_crttab;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALTED.wrapper_crttab TO batch;
```

Now let's run it:

```
CONN batch/batch
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
EXEC ALTED.wrapper_crttab;
```

This causes the error:

> Error at line 1:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The tables referenced do exist.

The call to the `p1` proc confirms that all the privileges bundled with IMP_FULL_DATABASE are present, including `CREATE ANY TABLE`, `DROP ANY TABLE`, `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE`.

If I do this:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO batch;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO batch;

CONN batch/batch

EXEC EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE atled.the_tab AS SELECT id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(cc,2) AS cc FROM ARCHIVE.table_b;
```

This works.

If I change the `CREATE TABLE` stmt to remove the `DBMS_CRYPTO` call, it works as well.

The actual package/proc that is called creates a number of tables fine when run as above, but fails on the case when DBMS_CRYPTO is called in any `CREATE TABLE` stmt.

If I grant the `batch` user the `CREATE ANY TABLE`, `SELECT ANY TABLE` and `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE` privs directly and run the `CREATE TABLE` command as batch directly then that works too.

So this is not (I think) a straight ORA-942 error, but something related to a chain of privileges to DBMS_CRYPTO, and only when executed in a package stored procedure, but what exactly I do not know.

**UPDATE 1**

If I create a wrapper for DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION batch.crypto_hash ( pcc IN CLOB ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
   RETURN DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(pcc,2);
END;
/
```

Then replace the `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(cc,2)` in the `CREATE TABLE` stmt with `batch.crypto_hash(cc)` then it works!!!

So, DEFINITELY not a issue with grants on teh tables being referenced, but more likely something internal with the way DBMS_CRYPTO works. Perhaps it reads a look up table somewhere. I tried `GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_I18N to batch` as well before this but that didn't work.

So I have a workaround, but woudl still like to know why this happens.

Comment: do you have a read access on ARCHIVE.table_b?

Comment: @Nick , no, not directly. The `GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE ALTED.wrapper_crttab;` means anyone running that proc will have those privs. Also, if I remove the `DBMS_CRYPTO` call it works. The cause/crux of this error is calling DBMS_CRYPTO.

Comment: nice, I can see you able to create a workaround for this. I happened to use same workaround before 'using a function' rather than a subquery -- different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this:

```
... FROM ARCHIVE.table_b
```

User, who is supposed to select from that table, has to have `SELECT` privileges on it. It can be granted

1. via role
2. directly

If you granted the privilege via **role**, it works - but **not in named PL/SQL procedures**. It will work in anonymous PL/SQL, but not in procedures, function, packages, so - check that and, possibly, grant `SELECT` on `table_b` directly to that user.

Comment: @Litttlefoot thanks. WHat you say makes perfect sense normally, but here  I am using CBAC, granting high privs to the stored procedure. Moreover, leaving everything as above, but taking out the DBMS_CRYPTO call works. SO underlying tables privs are OK. I do wonder if it has anything to do with the CC column being a CLOB, and there is some LOB_SEGMENT priv under the hood that is missing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any other idea. I tried to Google for it (as you, probably, did), but no luck ... I hope you'll fix it and - if you do - post the solution here, please.

Comment: See my UPDATE 1 above. I posted details of the solution/workaround.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you. I'm glad you fixed it.